# Figure caption and CSS stylesheet for RMarkdown

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I'm using isoslides in RMarkdown. I'm using this to style the figure captions in a separate style sheet:

```
p.caption {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-style: italic;
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;  
  text-align: justify;
}
```

I'm getting a warning sign that says: `Element p.caption is overqualified.` And the style is not being applied to the document. I have `figure_caption: true` included in the document YAML. This code is taken directly from this [RMD styling tutorial](https://holtzy.github.io/Pimp-my-rmd/#custom_caption); the same command is also cited in my CSS book *CSS: The Definitive Guide*.

This is the error, and, as you can see, the 'p' is not highlighted as if the .css does recognise it.

[image]

The output I'm currently getting is the same as the default.

Here is the HTML (I think?).

```
<p class="caption">

Labels show degree value

</p>
```

Comment: provide HTML code also.

Comment: @MehrajKhan, I've updated with the HTML, or what I think to be the HTML.

Comment: @elliot have you tried removing the `p` and just having `.caption`?

Comment: @coops, I did; and I think I just found my problem. I copied a block of CSS for a footer that had p.caption {} as well and included in the RMD itself. So I think it was overriding it. When I removed it things started working correctly.

Comment: @elliot you already give a class name so no need to write attribute.